# Horizontal infinite scrolling with SKSpriteNode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, width

I am trying to make my game character loop around the screen infinitely like this: http://i.imgur.com/F2yuqen.gifv

Basically, there are three characters. One spawns in the middle of the screen, and the other two spawn exactly the screen width away on opposite sides and move with the main player. Once the main player's x position is less than 0, or greater than the screen width, it is placed back into the middle of the screen. This makes it infinite in essence.

It works great in processing, but in swift my variables for screen width `self.size.width` seem much larger than the actual screen width when I run the game in the iOS simulator. This makes the character movement not seem smooth and if it is cut off on one side, it does not show up on the other side like it does in the first example.

Example: http://i.imgur.com/gLS4ijK.gifv

Again, I think it has something to do with `self.size.width` not actually being the width of the display in the simulator.

Code:

Comment: When I println the sprite size t says 50. Is that pixels or points?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had to add

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

to GameViewController.swift